# How to trace Memory References requested by Operating system?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory, page-replacement

i'm working on page replacement algorithm.
for testing algorithm, i'm trying to analyse pattern in which OS would request Memory( Pages ). 
How should i trace these Memory request (Virtual) ?

Comment: In case of `ReactOS` adding hooks to http://svn.reactos.org/svn/reactos/trunk/reactos/hal/halx86/generic/memory.c?view=markup seems like good 1st guess. Which OS you want to analyze?

Comment: i'm looking for Linux and Windows. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/mm ?